# Why spring cannot find beans.xml?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am learning spring and put the Beans.xml into main/resources folder. I am using maven to manage project.

However when running, it cannot find the Beans.xml

```
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "Beans.xml");
```

The error is Exception in thread "main"

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
```

I am using Intellij, want to know why? I am using spring 4.3.4

Comment: You're assuming that Beans.xml ending up in the classpath at runtime.  Check your assumptions.  The JVM tells you it did not.  Are you packaging with Maven?  Is this Spring deployed as a WAR on a Java EE app server or Spring Boot with an executable JAR?

Comment: In which way are you running the application?

Comment: I am running using "Run Main", not package into WAR or JAR

Comment: Then you need to make Idea use `src/main/resources` as a part of classpath when running the "Run Main". In Eclipse, these are called "run configurations", but I have no Idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/resources/beans.xml");
```

file: prefix point to file system resources, not classpath.

Comment: it works, but is there any configuration change that I could just specify beans.xml

Comment: If this works then your file is named `beans.xml` and not `Beans.xml`. Don't use the construct mentioned in this answer as that will break as soon as you deploy your application (or create a jar file). This will only work in your IDE.  Use `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")` notice the lower case instead of uppercase starting character.

Comment: it is not regarding the case. I am using windows, so case is not sensitive\

Answer (score 0):

Despite the @Hiccup's answer is right, but it is not accurate because if your application is FileSystem dependent (using the "file:" prefix) and you package this app and execute it with java commands there will be thrown the same exception, so you can add this prefix:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:Beans.xml");
```

But this is correct just if you have configured Maven (or Ant or Ivy) to tell IntelliJ to locate resources from main/resources folder.

So, if the previous affirmation is not your case, you have to move your Beans.xml to src/main/java.